# Cannot connect to website - SSL handshaking fails

Tags: windows-7, ssl, wireshark, curl

So I cannot connect to certain websites.  Just a few, most are OK.  The one I really care about is paypal.com.

I have done the usual things.  Let's see:

- Cleared browsing history
- Tried different browsers
- Uninstalled and downloaded/installed fresh browser
- System restored to before problem first occurred
- Installed all system patches
- Checked my etc/hosts
- Flushed the DNS cache
- Checked firewall
- Switched on & off virus protection
- Switched on and off ad blocking
- pinged the sites
- Connect directly to ISP access point without using router

Eventually, I decided to look at what curl is saying in detail

```
== Info: About to connect() to www.paypal.com port 443 (#0)
== Info:   Trying 66.211.169.2... == Info: connected
== Info: SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
=> Send SSL data, 110 bytes (0x6e)
0000: 01 00 00 6a 03 01 4f 6c aa 8c 57 2b 3d 1e 74 64 ...j..Ol..W+=.td
0010: c1 27 25 a5 3a 12 7f 3f 41 0a 17 15 2e c9 67 7c .'%.:.?A.....g|
0020: b3 e1 f6 9a db a9 00 00 2a 00 39 00 38 00 35 00 ........*.9.8.5.
0030: 16 00 13 00 0a 00 33 00 32 00 2f 00 07 00 05 00 ......3.2./.....
0040: 04 00 15 00 12 00 09 00 14 00 11 00 08 00 06 00 ................
0050: 03 00 ff 01 00 00 17 00 00 00 13 00 11 00 00 0e ................
0060: 77 77 77 2e 70 61 79 70 61 6c 2e 63 6f 6d       www.paypal.com
(hangs here for ever)
```

This looks to me like paypal is refusing to reply to the first SSL handshake.

I don't know much about SSL, but compaing to the output from a site that works for me seems to make it obvious

```
== Info: About to connect() to www.cibc.com port 443 (#0)
== Info:   Trying 159.231.80.200... == Info: connected
== Info: SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
=> Send SSL data, 108 bytes (0x6c)
0000: 01 00 00 68 03 01 4f 6c ad 6a 1f 67 d5 84 c4 4b ...h..Ol.j.g...K
0010: 0d 49 ae d6 b9 5b c3 63 f9 48 aa 18 da 43 d1 32 .I...[.c.H...C.2
0020: 47 ae 17 e5 cd e9 00 00 2a 00 39 00 38 00 35 00 G.......*.9.8.5.
0030: 16 00 13 00 0a 00 33 00 32 00 2f 00 07 00 05 00 ......3.2./.....
0040: 04 00 15 00 12 00 09 00 14 00 11 00 08 00 06 00 ................
0050: 03 00 ff 01 00 00 15 00 00 00 11 00 0f 00 00 0c ................
0060: 77 77 77 2e 63 69 62 63 2e 63 6f 6d             www.cibc.com
== Info: SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
<= Recv SSL data, 74 bytes (0x4a)
0000: 02 00 00 46 03 01 00 00 58 cf 26 e2 e1 65 db 11 ...F....X.&..e..
0010: bc 6f 26 7b 3b 6d eb 14 5f ad 47 dd 86 ea 4d a3 .o&{;m.._.G...M.
0020: fb 9f b7 2a 54 3e 20 5f 6b 04 5a 12 38 64 5d 18 ...*T> _k.Z.8d].
0030: 65 9e e9 cd 61 eb 91 c1 16 25 61 30 bb 08 2a 78 e...a....%a0..*x
0040: b8 ee b8 7e f2 65 6a 00 04 00                   ...~.ej...
== Info: SSLv3, TLS handshake, CERT (11):

... and so on - working nicely eventually get some nice HTML
```

Now I am reaaly stuck.  This has been going on for five days, so I am pretty sure that the problem is not with paypal.  But what on my system could be interfering with the SSL handshaking done by curl with this particular site?

Next I installed WireShark to capture the packets being exchanged with paypal.com

```
No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
    123 118.847059  192.168.100.3         66.211.169.14         TCP      66     59884 > https [SYN] Seq=0 Win=8192 Len=0 MSS=1460 WS=4 SACK_PERM=1
    124 118.982913  66.211.169.14         192.168.100.3         TCP      66     https > 59884 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=4380 Len=0 MSS=1440 WS=1 SACK_PERM=1
    125 118.982981  192.168.100.3         66.211.169.14         TCP      54     59884 > https [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=66240 Len=0
    126 118.983728  192.168.100.3         66.211.169.14         SSL      240    Client Hello
    129 119.373787  192.168.100.3         66.211.169.14         SSL      240    [TCP Retransmission] Client Hello
    132 119.560671  66.211.169.14         192.168.100.3         SSL      153    [TCP Previous segment lost] Continuation Data
    133 119.560714  192.168.100.3         66.211.169.14         TCP      66     [TCP Dup ACK 129#1] 59884 > https [ACK] Seq=187 Ack=1 Win=66240 Len=0 SLE=4381 SRE=4480
```

V-e-r-y interesting!

The client Hello is being retransmitted, after less than 0.5 secs.  Why?  Could this be confusing things?  Can I control this somehow?

A reply is received from paypal, but is market as 'previous fragment lost' which would seem to my problem.  How to solve it???

It seems that this might well be a network issue.  It happens with two machines connected to this ISP.  However, when I connect one of the machines showing the problem on this network to the internet at a friends house who has a different ISP, the problem goes away!

( Note: How I connect to the internet (AFAIK ).  I connect the ethernet port on my computer to a small black box called a 'wireless access point'.  This in turn is connected to what looks like a ruggedized ethernet cable connected to a microwave ariel on my roof, which connects through a series of microwave arials to the internet. )

What do I say to the ISP?  They will not believe that their network is interfering with the SSL handshaking from certain sites, but not others.

[Here's a link](http://66.199.140.183/paypal.pcap) to the Wireshark capture of SSL handshaking

Comment: @maweeras Thank you.  I agree.  See note at end of my question.

Comment: "You should upload the netmon/wireshark trace of you attempting to connect to PayPal for someone here to analyse." I would be delighted to do so.  Who? How?

Comment: You can use something like www.skydrive.com to upload a file to a folder that ou can share as public. Then once uploaded, update the post with a link to it. Don't blame the ISP. Its your network devices that I suspect at this stage.

Comment: "Network devices"?  I connect my computer to the access point with an ethernet cable.

Comment: I will do so on Monday, when I am back at my desk.  I will add what little I know about connecting to my ISP to my question.

Comment: @maweeras link to wireshark capture added to question

Answer (score 1):

The retransmit of the packet happened as the client didnt see a response to the first client hello it sent. You seem to have a device from Zinwell or a rebadged version of such a device for your router. I would do some firmware updates if available. It would be better if you provide another sample trace as this one is incomplete/filtered. If you start wireshark/netmon before visiting the site, we will see details of the connect request and so on like below.

```
3   38.1779028  iexplore.exe    192.168.0.14    192.168.0.1 TCP TCP:Flags=......S., SrcPort=49301, DstPort=HTTP Alternate(8080), PayloadLen=0, Seq=1380476926, Ack=0, Win=8192 ( Negotiating scale factor 0x2 ) = 8192  {TCP:2, IPv4:1}
4   38.1781162  iexplore.exe    192.168.0.1 192.168.0.14    TCP TCP:Flags=...A..S., SrcPort=HTTP Alternate(8080), DstPort=49301, PayloadLen=0, Seq=92792191, Ack=1380476927, Win=16384 ( Negotiated scale factor 0x0 ) = 16384  {TCP:2, IPv4:1}
5   38.1786808  iexplore.exe    192.168.0.14    192.168.0.1 TCP TCP:Flags=...A...., SrcPort=49301, DstPort=HTTP Alternate(8080), PayloadLen=0, Seq=1380476927, Ack=92792192, Win=16425 (scale factor 0x2) = 65700   {TCP:2, IPv4:1}
6   38.1788535  iexplore.exe    192.168.0.14    192.168.0.1 HTTP    HTTP:Request, CONNECT www.paypal.com:443    {HTTP:3, TCP:2, IPv4:1}
7   38.3178172  iexplore.exe    192.168.0.1 192.168.0.14    TCP TCP:Flags=...A...., SrcPort=HTTP Alternate(8080), DstPort=49301, PayloadLen=0, Seq=92792192, Ack=1380477151, Win=65311 (scale factor 0x0) = 65311   {TCP:2, IPv4:1}
8   38.3784467  iexplore.exe    192.168.0.1 192.168.0.14    HTTP    HTTP:Response, HTTP/1.1, Status: Ok, URL: www.paypal.com:443    {HTTP:3, TCP:2, IPv4:1}
9   38.3826707  iexplore.exe    192.168.0.14    192.168.0.1 TLS TLS:TLS Rec Layer-1 HandShake: Client Hello.    {TLS:5, SSLVersionSelector:4, HTTP:3, TCP:2, IPv4:1}
10  38.5365475  iexplore.exe    192.168.0.1 192.168.0.14    TCP TCP:Flags=...A...., SrcPort=HTTP Alternate(8080), DstPort=49301, PayloadLen=0, Seq=92792299, Ack=1380477280, Win=65182 (scale factor 0x0) = 65182   {TCP:2, IPv4:1}
11  38.5485415  iexplore.exe    192.168.0.1 192.168.0.14    TLS TLS:TLS Rec Layer-1 HandShake: Server Hello.; TLS Rec Layer-2 HandShake: Certificate.   {TLS:5, SSLVersionSelector:4, HTTP:3, TCP:2, IPv4:1}
12  38.5486008  iexplore.exe    192.168.0.1 192.168.0.14    TCP TCP:[Continuation to #11]Flags=...A...., SrcPort=HTTP Alternate(8080), DstPort=49301, PayloadLen=1460, Seq=92793759 - 92795219, Ack=1380477280, Win=65182 (scale factor 0x0) = 65182    {TCP:2, IPv4:1}
13  38.5486008  iexplore.exe    192.168.0.1 192.168.0.14    TCP TCP:[Continuation to #11]Flags=...AP..., SrcPort=HTTP Alternate(8080), DstPort=49301, PayloadLen=1460, Seq=92795219 - 92796679, Ack=1380477280, Win=65182 (scale factor 0x0) = 65182    {TCP:2, IPv4:1}
```

Comment: Thank you for looking at this.  I have changed my ISP and this fixed the problem

Comment: @maweeras: same here: http://superuser.com/questions/897662/traffic-redirection-with-rasperry-pi-router - except for it works fine on the router itself but hangs on the notebook.