# Traffic redirection with Rasperry Pi router

Tags: router, iptables, nat, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I use a Rasperry Pi (running raspbian) as a wi-fi router. It redirects traffic from the Ethernet wire (eth0 - wire + ppp0 - L2TP connection, lx2tp used for it) to wlan0 (USB wi-fi dongle, hostapd used for the AP functionality).

And the problem is, some sites are loaded really slow or not loaded at all.
Take for instance soundcloud .com - the command `curl -L soundcloud.com` performs in a snap on the router itself but hangs forever on a laptop connected to it via Wi-Fi. It must be traffic redirection issue.

Here is my /etc/network/interfaces:

```
pi@pi ~ $ cat /etc/network/interfaces
auto lo

iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet dhcp

iface wlan0 inet static
    address 192.168.1.1
    netmask 255.255.255.0

up iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.ipv4.nat
```

And here are the redirection rules:

```
pi@pi ~ $ cat 1.sh
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o ppp0 -j MASQUERADE
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i ppp0 -o wlan0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i wlan0 -o ppp0 -j ACCEPT
sudo sh -c "iptables-save > /etc/iptables.ipv4.nat"
```

Is there something wrong with this setup?

UPD:

Route table at the Pi:

```
pi@pi ~ $ route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         *               0.0.0.0         U     0      0        0 ppp0
10.89.64.0      *               255.255.248.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
85.21.0.0       10.89.64.1      255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 eth0
hdns2.corbina.n 10.89.64.1      255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eth0
192.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wlan0
hdns1.corbina.n 10.89.64.1      255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eth0
```

UPD2:

Turns out is't some SSL issue (that's from vagrant Ubuntu box on the OSX host):

```
vagrant@precise64:~$ curl -v -L soundcloud.com/pure_virtual
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 93.184.220.127...
* Connected to soundcloud.com (93.184.220.127) port 80 (#0)
> GET /pure_virtual HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.38.0
> Host: soundcloud.com
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 302 Found
< Date: Sat, 04 Apr 2015 17:38:06 GMT
< Location: https://soundcloud.com/pure_virtual
* Server am/2 is not blacklisted
< Server: am/2
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
< Content-Length: 0
< 
* Connection #0 to host soundcloud.com left intact
* Issue another request to this URL: 'https://soundcloud.com/pure_virtual'
* Found bundle for host soundcloud.com: 0x7f73d4f2d0b0
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 93.184.220.127...
* Connected to soundcloud.com (93.184.220.127) port 443 (#1)
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: none
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):

* Operation timed out after 0 milliseconds with 0 out of 0 bytes received
* Closing connection 1
curl: (28) Operation timed out after 0 milliseconds with 0 out of 0 bytes received
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appeared to be an MTU/packet fragmenting issue, solved with this iptables spell:

```
iptables -I FORWARD -p tcp --tcp-flags SYN,RST SYN -j TCPMSS --clamp-mss-to-pmtu
```

Comment: that spell just appeared?  ;-) what spell made it appear?!

Comment: @barlop, found it on my ISP's forum)

Answer (score 1):

Your setup appears to be perfectly standard. Which means that the problem could be any number of things.

The most direct way to find the problem would be to take a look at how the traffic is flowing using [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) - a program that will allow you to see how the packets are flowing using a GUI.

First, capture some data on the Raspberry Pi with the following command:

`sudo tcpdump -n -w part1.pcap not port 22`

(Explanation: The `-n` flag stops DNS resolving, since we don't care about that. The `-w part1.pcap` part will write the data to a pcap file so that we can feed it to WireShark later. The `not port 22` will filter out the SSH traffic, which we don't care about.)

Now, with that command running, open up a second SSH connection to the Raspberry Pi and do a `curl -L soundcloud.com` (and other related commands). Once you are finished, go back to the first SSH window and do a "Ctrl + C" to stop the tcpdump. This will create the `part1.pcap` file.

For round 2, do the same thing but with a different file name, like so:

`sudo tcpdump -n -w part2.pcap not port 22`

Now, go manually surf to soundcloud.com on your PC. After it finishes loading, end the tcpdump with "Ctrl + C" again.

Finally, download and install Wireshark on your PC, transfer the 2 pcap files, and then use Wireshark to view them. By comparing the two files, you should find a powerful clue about what is happening.

Comment: thanks! I saw at pcap files through Wireshark (used it for the 1st time) but that made no sense to me:( If anything, I updated the post with the router's routing table. Other than that, I conducted some experiments on accessing soundcloud.com on the laptop 1) with the network cable attached and 2) via Wi-Fi to Pi, and (1) clearly works well while (2) is dead slow and most of the time just hangs.

Comment: also please take a look at the UPD2 - an SSL issue showed up when I finally got to wait for the `curl -L soundcloud.com` to finish..

Comment: Hey, I've just extracted the relevant packets for the Raspberry Pi -> Soundcloud connection (https://yadi.sk/d/31xw4xdyfmFJS) and my laptop -> Soundcloud one (https://yadi.sk/d/P4amCleHfmFMZ), please take a look. From what I understand, it's just a visualization of the "SSL handshake timeout" error, but the reason still unknown)